# How to fix Checker Framework Error java: [contracts.precondition.not.satisfied] unguarded call to method 'method()' requiring 'Holding.y.z' to be held

Tags: java, checker-framework

How to properly call `method()` from `main(..)`?

```
class LockCheckerTest {
    static class Y {
        final Lock z = new ReentrantLock(true);
    }

    private final static Date x = new Date((long) (System.currentTimeMillis() * Math.random()));
    private final static Y y = new Y();

    @Holding({"x", "y.z"})
    @ReleasesNoLocks
    static void method() {
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        synchronized (x) {  // acquire intrinsic lock of 'x' 
            synchronized (y) { // locking 'y' is not required, just trying to compile
                y.z.lock(); // acquire explicit lock 'y.z'
                method();  // ERROR
                y.z.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error:(37, 23) java: [contracts.precondition.not.satisfied] unguarded call to method 'method()' requiring 'Holding.y.z' to be held

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this was a bug in the Checker Framework:  it knew how to handle variables declared as [`ReentrantLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html), but not how to handle variables declared as its interface [`Lock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html).

That bug is [fixed](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/commit/49f1247fadf72e9dd60d1c84277ab80e3b283d64) in the [Git version control repository](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework) but not in the [current release, version 2.1.1](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/releases).

Using the version from Git, your code type-checks for me, after fixing one problem:  your `main` method needs to be annotated as [`@MayReleaseLocks`](http://types.cs.washington.edu/dev/checker-framework/api/org/checkerframework/checker/lock/qual/MayReleaseLocks.html).